# How to explain a regression model has worse MAE but better R2 score than another model?

Tags: statistics, regression, metrics

I have the following results for the two models that I am comparing for a regression problem. I wonder why model 1 has better R2 score, but worse MAE? How is this possible? The results on the same testing dataset.

Model 1:
MAE: 9.56
R2: 0.63

Model 2:
MAE: 9.21
R2: 0.60